# Msi files are not installed if used in a bundle

Tags: wix

I just wrote a wxs file with two msipackage but for an unknow reason it doesn´t install any of my msi.

Here is my sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="MyTest" Version="0.1" Manufacturer="MySelf" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-222222222222">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64' SourceFile="my32.msi" />
            <MsiPackage InstallCondition='VersionNT64' SourceFile="my64.msi" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

I don´t have any errors while running :

```
candle.exe -ext WixBalExtension bundle.wxs
light.exe -ext WixBalExtension bundle.wixobj
```

When I run my bundle.exe it says installation complete but nothing has been installed on my machine. Bundle.exe looks correct ~175Mb, my32.msi ~84Mb, my64.msi ~99.
my32.msi and my64.msi works well, both generated with wix ... I also tested my wxs script with two simple msi and in this case it does work. Is there anything special with large files ?

The purpose of my project, as you may understand, is to build an install exe containing both 32 and 64 bits installers.

[EDIT] 
Installation log :

```
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i001: Burn v3.11.2.4516, Windows v10.0 

(Build 17763: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\erwand\AppData\Local\Temp\{B2336622-4B6B-473C-9559-1ECC77248BB5}\.cr\bundle.exe
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\bundle.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=636 -burn.filehandle.self=632'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\bundle.exe'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\erwand\AppData\Local\Temp\MyTest_20200102160338.log'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'MyTest'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'MySelf'
[4710:2A9C][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[4710:2A9C][2020-01-02T16:03:38]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '0.1.0.0'
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i103: Detected related package: {8F149791-D1D8-4245-A032-1065F5D1F81B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 3.26.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i103: Detected related package: {8F149791-D1D8-4245-A032-1065F5D1F81B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 3.26.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i101: Detected package: my32.msi, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i101: Detected package: my64.msi, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[4710:2A9C][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i201: Planned package: my32.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i201: Planned package: my64.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i300: Apply begin
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:41]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i361: Created a system restore point.
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\erwand\AppData\Local\Temp\{486F27D5-FBAE-43F3-B6B3-D51A8B438498}\.be\bundle.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}\bundle.exe'
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}, version: 0.1.0.0
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[4048:3018][2020-01-02T16:03:43]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:44]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 0.1.0.0
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\erwand\AppData\Local\Temp\MyTest_20200102160338.log
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = MySelf
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = MyTest
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\bundle.exe
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {634653fa-b057-4830-b7b5-a0123024f086}
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\Users\erwand\Desktop\testWIX\bundle.exe
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleUILevel = 4
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 0.1.0.0
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i410: Variable: WixStdBALanguageId = 1033
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:46]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Just added the installation log, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for helping !

Comment: I wondering if it's because it thinks it's a downgrade? From the log: 
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i103: Detected related package: {8F149791-D1D8-4245-A032-1065F5D1F81B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 3.26.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[4710:5298][2020-01-02T16:03:39]i103: Detected related package: {8F149791-D1D8-4245-A032-1065F5D1F81B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 3.26.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade

Comment: Okay, I already have a version 3.26... installed on my machine. But how can I enforce wix to show my installer ? Even if there is an old version.